# Server Control as a parameter to SqlDataSource to filter results

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

**Problem**

I am trying to use a text box `txtSearch` to filter results from a `SqlDataSource`.

My query:

```
SELECT 
    [id], [username], [name] 
FROM 
    [dbo].[users] 
WHERE 
    @filter IS NULL OR 
    LEN(@filter) = 0 OR 
    [name] LIKE ('%'+@filter+'%')
```

ASPX markup:

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
</div>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [username], [name] FROM [dbo].[users] WHERE @filter IS NULL OR LEN(@filter) = 0 OR [name] LIKE ('%'+@filter+'%')">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" DefaultValue="" 
             Name="filter" Type="String" PropertyName="Text" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C# code-behind:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Table `[dbo].[users]`:

```
id        name        username
----      ----        --------
  0       Jack        jhenry
  1       Jim         jcallaway
  2       Phillip     pmcarthur
```

I simply get an empty grid, then I tried to set the default value to `" "` (single space) and modified `@filter IS NULL` to `@filter = ''`. This gave me the whole grid as expected but when I enter a value in the textbox and hit **`Search`**, nothing happens. How do I get the filter hooked up to the `SqlDataSource` with least effort?

Dirty fix:

Searching for a space `" "` instead of `NULL` works, but I have set `ConvertEmptyStringToNull = True`

```
SELECT 
    [id], [username], [name] 
FROM 
    [dbo].[users] 
WHERE 
    @filter = ' ' OR 
    LEN(@filter) = 0 OR 
    [name] LIKE ('%'+@filter+'%')
```

I would rather use `IS NULL` to make it clean, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you add `Type="String"` to ControlParameter and try with the following query?

```
SELECT [id], [username], [name]
FROM [dbo].[users]
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(@filter)) = '' 
   OR [name] LIKE '%'+ LTRIM(RTRIM(@filter)) +'%'

<SelectParameters>
   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" 
           DefaultValue="" 
           Name="filter" 
           Type="String"
           PropertyName="Text" />
</SelectParameters>
```

**Updated**:

You need to rebind datasource instead of Grid.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SQLDataSource1.DataBind();
}
```

Stored procedure:

If you want validation logic, it is better to use a stored procedure.

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUsers
    @Filter NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SearchFilter BIT
    SET @SearchFilter = 1

    IF (@Filter IS NULL OR RTRIM(LTRIM(@Filter)) = N'')
        SET @SearchFilter = 0   

    SET @Filter = ISNULL(@Filter, '')
    SET @Filter = '%' + RTRIM(LTRIM(@Filter)) + '%'          

    SELECT [id], [username], [name]
    FROM [dbo].[users] WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE @SearchFilter = 0
       OR [name] LIKE @Filter
END
```

Comment: I tried `Type="String"` and trimming the parameter value with `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` but no success

Comment: What is value of name look like in database, and what is your search parameter? Could you show me a couple of sample data?

Comment: `SQLDataSource1.DataBind()` did not help but when I the select query with `LTRIM(RTRIM(@filter)) = '<single space>'` OR [name] LIKE '%'+ LTRIM(RTRIM(@filter)) +'%'` and set the default value `<single space>` it works. Note: <single space> is not the phrase but just a space. I would like to use `IS NULL` instead

Comment: If you want validation logic, it is better to use Store Procedure. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, I will try it tomorrow and let you know if that works!! Thank you

Comment: I did not use the same SP but I used the idea and I figured out disabling `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` allows empty string to be passed to the DB which is processed through the trims and `LEN()` hence I did not have to explicitly check empty strings and single spaces. I will let you modify the answer if you think it is necessary but, This is the solution I was looking for!

Comment: also consider `SET @filter = LTRIM(RTRIM(@filter))` to prevent repeating it on each comparison